# How to logout user logged in with custom devise strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, logout

I need to  logout a user that has been logged in my Rails app using custom Devise authentication strategy. This strategy is used in addition to database_authenticable strategy. Is there a logic I need to add to my custom implementation of authenticate_user! method in custom strategy? Also do I need to implement destroy method in a custom sessions controller?

Currently my custom strategy logs in the user fine (hard coded for now) but I cannot logout the user as logout action calls my custom implementation of authenticate_user! again and they are logged in again.

Answer (score 1):

So far as I understood correctly, is that, let any action to `logout` the `current_user` in devise. If it's so then it can be implemented like this

Let's say ,

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def some_action
    if some_logic == true #implement some_logic to return boolean(true/false)
      sign_out resource
      flash[:notice] = ''
      flash[:error] = 'You are logged out!'
      root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think all this should be required, just because I have implemented custom strategy. If the user is logged out properly (which is really my question) they should be taken to sign in page if they are redirected to page (home page in this case) that requires authentication.  Do I even need a custom sessions controller in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use skip_before_action callback in this case like in your controller put below code before all actions

```
 skip_before_action :authenticate_user, only: [:your_logout_action]
```

This will skip authentication for your method and user won't log in again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue. The issue was that I had hard coded `valid?` method to return true all the time. When I added the logic to return true only if email and password params are present then the custom auth works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

##### Make user log out by manually.

```
sign_out(current_user) if current_user.present?
```